# Why is this throwing error Bad switch statement

Tags: perl, switch-statement

When i am only using 6 cases the switch is working and when i add the 7th case its giving error

```
switch($A){
    case 0 {do something}
    case 1 {do something}
    case 2 {do something}
    case 3 {do something}
    case 4 {do something}
    case 5 {do something}
    case 6 {do something}
    default{}
}
```

Comment: What is `switch`? Is it from a module or something?

Comment: It should say `else`, not `default` (Unless you have Perl 6, that is). See: https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Switch.html

Comment: added else still not working

Comment: Please update your question showing the code that is still not working

Comment: If this is the old [Switch](https://perldoc.pl/5.12.5/Switch) module, it was removed from Perl core in 5.14 and should be avoided at all costs. It's a terrible source filter that causes inscrutable issues throughout your code. The [experimental switch feature](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Switch-Statements) should also be avoided as it relies on confusing and complicated behavior of both when and smartmatch. Consider [Switch::Plain](https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch::Plain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Switch](https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch) module. There was a time when this was included in the standard Perl distribution (from 5.8 to 5.10) but it's a source filter, which is a short way of saying "this does incredibly complicated things to parse your Perl code and is almost guaranteed to break in hard-to-find ways at some point".

Please don't use it.

But if you insist on using it, then replace `default` with `else`.